# MSWord 2010 text won't shift across the entire line

Tags: microsoft-word

I copied some text from a pdf file and pasted it onto a word document. The problem is that the text does not run on the entire line, rather appears only in a small section of the word page. Snapshot attached.
[image]

When I hit the backspace or type any characters, they still appear only in that small area and the rest of the page is left blank(Text appears on the left side, and the right side is completely empty).

I want my text to appear normally i.e. on the entire line and don't want to lose the style of the text(color+font+bullets).

Comment: Go to View, and check the box next to Ruler. Are the margins normal?

Comment: Paste-special as `TEXT` and see how the results come up. If it turns out to be normal and we can nail down what really the problem could be - "formatting" or "ruler" issue

Comment: Yes, it was indeed the ruler. Thanks @MC10